# Delegate method is not working in 1.7 jquery library

Tags: jquery

At first we were using jquery 1.4 then we migrated to jquery 1.7 after that Delegate method is not working in 1.7 jquery library tried to use .on method but it does not work.

```
$( "body" ).delegate( "p", "click", function() { $( this ).after( "
////Another paragraph!

" ); });
```

Comment: whether the script is in the header

Answer (score 1):

`.delegate()` is deprecated in jquery version 1.7+.use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead:

```
  $( "body" ).on("click","p",function() { 
     //code here
   });
```

Comment: actually i have tried everything like on ,live and bind method for that particular link it doesnot work may be there is some confliction from another jquery library.dont know

Comment: @punit: Look at on syntax carefully. First argument for `.on()` is event and then selector.

Comment: even if it is deprecated is should work... but as far as I know it is not deprecated... from docs `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method. For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates for the two methods:`

Answer (score 0):

Use `On()` `.delegate()` is deprecated

```
$(document).on("click","p",function() { 
     //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function() { $( this ).after( " Another paragraph!
" ); });
```